# Trying to set a mouse hover function to change color of divs when using .foreach

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have a `.forEach` function that turns `divs` red when my mouse hovers over them. This is what I have so far:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
boxes = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for (i=0; i<=2000; i++) {
    const box = document.createElement('div')
    box.classList.add('pixel')
    canvas.appendChild(box)
}

boxes.forEach((pixel) => {
    addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        setTimeout(pixel.classList.add('red'), 5000);
    })
});
```

Comment: What is your question? That is, what goes wrong with the current code?

Comment: Sorry, it is turning everything red and there is no 5 second delay until it goes white, it just stays red. How can i change this to make it turn 1 div red when hovering and change back after 5 secs

Comment: You've to attach the event listeners to the div elements, currently you're setting multiple listeners to `window`. See also [how setTimeout works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

Answer (score 0):

you actually don't have to add another class list for your `div`

you can just use CSS to make the element goes red whenever you hover them like this

```css
.pixel:hover {
background-color : red,
}
```

and that's it

also if you want to make an animation and delay for the hovered div you can use animation property

```css
pixel:hover {
animation : color,
animation-delay : 5s
}

@keyframes color {
0% { 
background-color : white
}
100% {
background-color : red
}
}
```

that's all you need with CSS, no need for JS

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the original code that prevent it from working as expected:

1. `boxes` is empty because at the time of running `querySelectorAll('div')`, no divs exist. Unless your `canvas` is also a div, in which case it will only find the canvas div element instead. Otherwise, empty.
2. By using `addEventListener`, you're invoking `window.addEventListener` (i.e. the top level addEventListener), which is acting on the window itself. You want to target each element, so you should be using `pixel.addEventListener` (but more on this in a bit).

So modifying your current solution slightly by moving the search for `pixel` class elements to AFTER the creation loop + doing `pixel.addEventListener`, which attaches the event listener to each pixel div, the following snippet works. (But keep reading after the snippet).

```js
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const DELAY = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
  const box = document.createElement('div')
  box.classList.add('pixel')
  canvas.appendChild(box)
}

boxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('pixel'));

boxes.forEach((pixel) => {
  pixel.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    setTimeout(() => pixel.classList.add('red'), DELAY);
  })

  pixel.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    setTimeout(() => pixel.classList.remove('red'), DELAY);
  })
});
```

```css
.pixel {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 4px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="canvas">
</section>
```

---

However, in the above example that's only 20 event listeners. It also doesn't work if you dynamically add more pixel elements - they wont have the associated event listeners. In your original code, you want 2000 elements. That's 2000 event listeners on the page (4000 if you did my example by adding a mouseout event as well to remove the added class).

A better way to scale this for dynamic + large numbers of elements is by just having 1 single event listener on the page and checking to see what element is being targeted:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.classes.includes('pixel')){
          e.target.classList.add('red');
     }
 });
```

This creates a **single**, dynamic event listener on the whole document that checks for the target it's hovering on. This way whether you have 2000 or 2 million elements, you only have 1 event listener effectively checking your hover state.

Note: If all you want to do is just change the color, you can use the other  answer and do this via CSS without any event handling. But if you have a reason to do this within javascript (i.e. dynamic color, maybe you want some other javascript code to run when something is hovered over), the above approach is ideal.